# Adding multiple listeners which will listen to different RabbitMQ queue not working

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I hava following spring xml configuration

```
<bean id="connectionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
 <constructor-arg value="xxxxxxxx"/>
        <property name="username" value="xxxxx"/>
        <property name="password" value="xxxxx"/>
        <property name="channelCacheSize" value="25"/>
        <property name="virtualHost" value="/"/>
        <property name="port" value="3453"/>
 </bean>

 <rabbit:template id="tutorialTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>
 <!-- 1st queue -->             
 <rabbit:queue id="veliteQueue" name="ES_queue" durable="true" auto-delete="false" exclusive="false"/>
    
 <rabbit:direct-exchange id="myExchange" durable="true" name="ES_exchange">
     <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding queue="veliteQueue" key="logstash"></rabbit:binding>
     </rabbit:bindings>
 </rabbit:direct-exchange>

  <!-- 2nd Queue -->
 <rabbit:queue id="veliteQueue1" name="ES_queue_Temp" durable="true" auto-delete="false" exclusive="false"/> 

  <rabbit:direct-exchange id="myExchange1" durable="true" name="ES_exchange_temp">
    <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding queue="ES_queue_Temp" key="logstash_temp"></rabbit:binding>
    </rabbit:bindings>
   </rabbit:direct-exchange> 
   <!-- 2 Listeners for 2 queue's mentioned above --> 
   <bean id="aListener" class="com.vzw.es.cosumer.SpringMessageListener" autowire="byName"/>
<bean id="aListener1" class="com.vzw.es.cosumer.SpringMessageListener1" autowire="byName"/>

<rabbit:listener-container id="myListenerContainer" connection-factory="connectionFactory" acknowledge="auto" prefetch="750" concurrency="1">
    <rabbit:listener ref="aListener" queues="veliteQueue"/>
    <rabbit:listener ref="aListener1" queues="veliteQueue1"/>
</rabbit:listener-container>
```

Now in my Java code I have 2 Listener classes: com.vzw.es.cosumer.SpringMessageListener and com.vzw.es.cosumer.SpringMessageListener1. Now When I am running my main class only 1 listener's onMessage method is getting invoked i.e. SpringMessageListener1, I did check from RabbitMQ prespective and bothe queues have enough messages to consume.

Also when I comment out the 2nd queue and its listener from xml SpringMessageListener works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in the container parser, each listener gets its own container (the namespace is just a convenient way to specify common attributes). If you remove the `id="myListenerContainer"`, it will work - because each container gets a (different) generated name. With the id specified, both beans get the same name, and the last definition replaces the first.

Alternatively, declare two separate container elements, with different IDs, and each having just one listener.

Thanks for finding this.

Please open a [JIRA issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/AMQP)

EDIT: This issue was [resolved in version 1.2.1](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-332).

Comment: Created a JIRA ticket and its assigned to you :) BTW after removing the id field it did work for me. Thanks !!!

Comment: Is it possible to have 2 listener-container with each having multiple listeners ? Its not working for me.

Comment: Yes, of course you can have multiple containers with multiple listeners. 'It's not working for me' is far too little information. I suggest you start a new question rather than commenting here and include configuration and exactly what you mean by "not working".