# Adding multiple listener-container, with ids, does not seem to work

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have a rabbitMQ configuration where in I need to have two separate listener-containers, each having a set of listeners. Here is a snippet from rabbitmq-context.xml:

```
<rabbit:listener-container
connection-factory="connectionFactory" message-converter="jsonMessageConverter" 
auto-startup="true" 
acknowledge="manual"
requeue-rejected="true"
concurrency="5"
task-executor="myTaskExecutor" >
       <rabbit:listener queues="Queue1" ref="myQ1Listener" method="onMessage"/>
</rabbit:listener-container>

<rabbit:listener-container
connection-factory="connectionFactory" message-converter="jsonMessageConverter" 
auto-startup="true" 
acknowledge="manual"
requeue-rejected="false"
concurrency="5"
task-executor="myTaskExecutor" >
       <rabbit:listener queues="Queu2" ref="myQ2Listener" method="onMessage"/>
</rabbit:listener-container>
```

If these are specified **without an id** all the listeners are started on initialization.

If I go ahead and specify an id to one of them (which I want to reference in another bean), the other listener-container (without the id) does not get initialized.

If I specify ids with both these listener-containers (and do not reference those ids anywhere), still listeners from only one of the listener-containers are initialized.

Can anybody help me understand if there its a configuration issue or is this a bug in RabbitMQ?

Comment: Show, please, the configuration, which couses an inssue. And specify which version of Spring AMQP you use.

Comment: RabbitMQ version is 3.0.4 . 
The configuration is pretty simple, just that I have 2 listener-container which seem to work if I don't specify ids.

Comment: No I meant *Spring AMQP* library

Comment: Especially **spring-rabbit.jar** version

Comment: Here are the versions:

spring-amqp-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-rabbit-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar

Comment: Right. That's why I suggested to upgrade: http://projects.spring.io/spring-amqp.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed (https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-332) according to SO question [Adding multiple listeners which will listen to different RabbitMQ queue not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726421/adding-multiple-listeners-which-will-listen-to-different-rabbitmq-queue-not-work).

So, show, please, the wrong config and try to upgrade to te latest Spring AMQP version.

Acutally we have similar [test-case](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/test/resources/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/listener/ListenFromAutoDeleteQueueTests-context.xml). I've just removed the `id` from nexted `<rabbit:listener>` elements and the `ListenFromAutoDeleteQueueTests` passed.

Please, check versions of Spring jars and try to use the latests.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply Artem.
My question is _not about multiple listeners_, but _multiple listener-containers_ . Please see the xml fragment just below the question.

Comment: Added more info to the answer

Comment: I am actually not using ids with the listeners in my configuration (if you refer to the xml configuration in the question). Listener is just referencing a Listener bean (myQ1Listener / myQ2Listener).

Comment: You should upgrade and let us know how it is with the latest version.

Comment: As you can see from the issue that Artem pointed you to (AMQP-332), this was fixed in 1.2.1. The current version is 1.3.5.